# Align Label with respect to TextField

Tags: html, css

I want my firstLabel to be just right side of the textfield on the same line.

[image]

```
    //css
    input[type="text"]{
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align:center;
    float:center;
    }

    label {
    float: right;
    text-align:right;
    color: white;
    font:12;
    } 

  //html
  <label for="first">First Value</label> 
  <input type="text" value="93" id="firstTF"/><br/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/x3gb6gcw/2/

html

```html
<input type="text" value="93" id="firstTF"/>
<label for="first">First Value</label>
```

css

```css
input[type="text"]{
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
}

label {
    text-align:left;
    color: #000;
    font:12;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: valid comment, in future answers definitely i will add the explanation. thanks again Danko

Answer (score 2):

Try this-

CSS Code-

```
input[type="text"]{
    display:inline;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    }

    label {
     display: inline;    
    text-align:right;
    color: white;
    font:12;
    }
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/gjamenoy/

In fiddle, I have changed the color of label since fiddle's background is white, so giving white color to label will not show it. Just to show it in fiddle I have given color black to it.

Answer (score 1):

Form controls are inline elements so if you just put your label tag after the textbox input control then they'll line up on their own(unless you set the width of the parent element too narrow for them both to fit naturally.

```
<input type="text" id="myText"/><label for="myText">My Label</label>
```

No need for CSS to position them this way, they float left by default.

Comment: Can still do it just by adding a line break after each label.